# I can't access to my website hosted on OVH (The requested URL / was not found on this server)

Tags: web-hosting, ovh

I have a website hosted on ovh.

I'm uploaded the source files in `www` directory and now when i try to access to my home page website i have this error : `The requested URL / was not found on this server`. In the `www` directory i have an `index.html` file.

Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your hostname is pointing to the right folder.

For OVH, you usually need to check the "Multisite" or the "Subdomain" settings to configure on which folder the user lands, depending on the (sub)domain.

Answer (score -1):

For OVH webhosting, each domains or subdomains is handle by a "multisite". You can setup a different folder for each multisite.

Did you check your multisite is setup for your "www" folder?

Comment: The problem is solved. In fact my hostname didn't pointed to the right folder www.

Comment: This is not an answer, you should comment to ask precisions. If you don't have the comment privilege, please gain reputation first.